# Save in the join table of a ternary relation using hibernate and struts2 is inserting long string in the FK column instead of the IDs

Tags: database, hibernate

Using hibernate - oracle DB, struts2, I am trying to insert in the join table of a ternary relation, but the result is: can not violate FK constraints, so after I removed the FK constraints from DB, I got: ORA-12899: value too large for column, when I looked into the DB, it's inserting too large text instead of the IDs.
I am taking the user info for jsp and the Group and application as checkboxes in the screen.

**Tables I have:** Users, Groups, Applications and the join table: user_group_application.

the classes are as following:

```
//-- Users Class --//
public class User implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9148926206758390091L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public Long id;
    @Email
    @Column(name="email", unique = true, nullable = false)  
    public String email;
    @Column(name="fullName")
    public String fullName;
    @Column(name="password")
    public String password;
    @Column(name="type")
    public String type; 
    @Column(name="location")
    public String location; 
    @Column(name="status")
    public String status;   

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pk.user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<UserGroupApplication> getUsergroupapplications() {
        return usergroupapplications;
    }
    public void setUsergroupapplications(
            Set<UserGroupApplication> usergroupapplications) {
        this.usergroupapplications = usergroupapplications;
    }

// -- setters and getters
}
```

the Application and the Groups class are on the same way ..

//-- the join classID --//

```
 @Embeddable
    public class UserGroupApplicationId implements java.io.Serializable{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -6790693372846798580L;

        private User user;
        private Group group;
        private Application application;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    public Group getGroup() {
        return group;
    }
    public void setGroup(Group group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    public Application getApplication() {
        return application;
    }
    public void setApplication(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        UserGroupApplicationId that = (UserGroupApplicationId) o;

        if (user != null ? !user.equals(that.user) : that.user != null) return false;
        if (group != null ? !group.equals(that.group) : that.group != null) return false;
        if (application != null ? !application.equals(that.application) : that.application != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result;
        result = (user != null ? user.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (group != null ? group.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (application != null ? application.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

}
```

//-- the join class is --//

```
@Entity
@Table(appliesTo = "RESOURCE_GROUP_APPLICATION")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.user", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "resourceid", nullable=false,updatable=false, insertable=false)),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.group", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "groupid", nullable=false,updatable=false, insertable=false)),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.application", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "applicationid", nullable=false,updatable=false, insertable=false))})

public class UserGroupApplication implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1949826260753890091L;
    private UserGroupApplicationId pk = new UserGroupApplicationId();
    public UserGroupApplication() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    public UserGroupApplicationId getPk() {
        return pk;
    }
    public void setPk(UserGroupApplicationId pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @Transient
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})           
    @JoinColumn(name = "RESOURCEID")
    public User getUser() {
        return getPk().getUser();
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        getPk().setUser(user);
    }

    @Transient
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})           
    @JoinColumn(name = "GROUPID")
    public Group getGroup() {
        return getPk().getGroup();
    }
    public void setGroup(Group group) {
        getPk().setGroup(group);
    }

    @Transient
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})           
    @JoinColumn(name = "APPLICATIONID")
    public Application getApplication(){
        return getPk().getApplication();
    }
    public void setApplication(Application application) {
        getPk().setApplication(application);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        UserGroupApplication that = (UserGroupApplication) o;

        if (getPk() != null ? !getPk().equals(that.getPk())
                : that.getPk() != null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return (getPk() != null ? getPk().hashCode() : 0);
    }


}
```

//-- the Action class is --//

```
public class UserAction extends ActionSupport {
public String addUser() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        this.user = user;
        // save or update the user
        session.saveOrUpdate(user);
        User us = (User) session.get(User.class, user.getId());
    Long gid;
    Group gr; 
    usrgrpsapps = new HashSet<UserGroupApplication>(0);
    userGroupApplication = new UserGroupApplication();      
    userGroupApplication.setUser(us);
    Long uid = userGroupApplication.getUser().getId();

    this.groupschecked = groupschecked;
    for (int i = 0; i < groupschecked.size(); i++) {
        gid = Long.parseLong(groupschecked.get(i));
        gr = (Group) session.get(Group.class, gid); 
        userGroupApplication.setGroup(gr);  

        Long appid;
        Application app;
        this.appschecked = appschecked;
        for (int j = 0; j < appschecked.size(); j++) {
            appid = Long.parseLong(appschecked.get(j));
            app = (Application) session.get(Application.class, appid);
            userGroupApplication.setApplication(app);   
            usrgrpsapps.add(userGroupApplication);
            us.getUsergroupapplications().add(userGroupApplication);
            app.getUserGroupApplication().add(userGroupApplication);
            gr.getUserGroupApplication().add(userGroupApplication);
            session.saveOrUpdate(us);
            session.saveOrUpdate(gr);
            session.saveOrUpdate(app);
            session.save(userGroupApplication);
            //session.save(usrgrpsapps);
        }
    }
    tx.commit();

    return SUCCESS;     
}
```

Comment: What is the column definition that returns a too large text?

Comment: all of them, the userid, applicationid, groupid.

Comment: They should not be a string type, rather than a numeric type to map the java objects.

Comment: The problem is when I save the objects in the join table like this: session.save(userGroupApplication); it saves long string not the FKs!

Comment: Are `userid, applicationid, groupid` FKs? If yes, then please answer the first question first.

Comment: yes they are FKs, the column is applicationid.

Comment: SQL Error: 12899, SQLState: 72000
ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) ORA-12899: value too large for column "DBName"."RESOURCE_GROUP_APPLICATION"."RESOURCEID" (actual: 2430, maximum: 1000)

Comment: Do you thankfully have any suggestion Mr. ROMAN C?